# Converting Output to CSV and Out-Grid

Tags: powershell, csv, pscustomobject

I have a file as below.
I want it to convert it to CSV and want to have the out grid view of it for items Drives,Drive Type,Total Space, Current allocation and Remaining space only.

```
PS C:\> echo $fileSys
Storage system address: 127.0.0.1
Storage system port: 443
HTTPS connection

1:    Name               = Extreme Performance
      Drives             = 46 x 3.8T SAS Flash 4
      Drive type         = SAS Flash
      RAID level         = 5
      Stripe length      = 13
      Total space        = 149464056594432 (135.9T)
      Current allocation = 108824270733312 (98.9T)
      Remaining space    = 40639785861120 (36.9T)
```

I am new to Powershell but I have tried below code for two of things but it's not even  getting me desired output.

```
$filesys | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^.+?(?<Total space>[0-9A-F]{4}\.[0-9A-F]{4}\.[0-9A-F]{4}).+?(?<Current allocation>\d+)$') {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'Total space'  = $matches['Total space']
            'Current allocation' = $matches['Current allocation']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `$fileSys` a single multi-line string, or an array of strings?

Comment: @mathias - I have added the output of filesys in question itself.

Comment: @GURUSINGH I think you misunderstand Mathias' question. Does running `$fileSys[0].GetType().FullName` return `System.Char` or `System.String`?

Comment: Alternatively, show us how you created `$fileSys` in the first place

Comment: $filesys is basically storing  the output of one storage box command

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen -Its System.String

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen- Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, the named capture groups cannot contain spaces.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named_matched_subexpression)

> Named Matched Subexpressions
>
> where name is a valid group name, and subexpression is any valid
> regular expression pattern. name must not contain any punctuation
> characters and cannot begin with a number.

Assuming this is a single string since your pattern attempts to grab info from multiple lines, you can forego the loop. However, even with that corrected, your pattern does not appear to match the data. It's not clear to me what you are trying to match or your desired output. Hopefully this will get you on the right track.

```
$filesys = @'
Storage system address: 127.0.0.1
Storage system port: 443
HTTPS connection

1:    Name               = Extreme Performance
      Drives             = 46 x 3.8T SAS Flash 4
      Drive type         = SAS Flash
      RAID level         = 5
      Stripe length      = 13
      Total space        = 149464056594432 (135.9T)
      Current allocation = 108824270733312 (98.9T)
      Remaining space    = 40639785861120 (36.9T)
'@

if($filesys -match '(?s).+total space\s+=\s(?<totalspace>.+?)(?=\r?\n).+allocation\s+=\s(?<currentallocation>.+?)(?=\r?\n)')
{
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Total space'  = $matches['totalspace']
        'Current allocation' = $matches['currentallocation']
    }
}

Total space              Current allocation     
-----------              ------------------     
149464056594432 (135.9T) 108824270733312 (98.9T)
```

**Edit**

If you just want the values in the parenthesis, modifying to this will achieve it.

```
if($filesys -match '(?s).+total space.+\((?<totalspace>.+?)(?=\)).+allocation.+\((?<currentallocation>.+?)(?=\))')
{
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Total space'  = $matches['totalspace']
        'Current allocation' = $matches['currentallocation']
    }
}

Total space Current allocation
----------- ------------------
135.9T      36.9T
```

Comment: Change both instances of `(?=\r)` to `(?=\r?\n)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen-Code work after making changes. Is it possible If I want to have the only values which are in brackets like 135. 9T and 98.9T

Comment: It's possible, guess you'll have to wait for @mathias to answer......

Comment: Usually people show gratitude for the assistance on stack overflow by upvoting and/or accepting answers.

Comment: @Doug- Friend i solved my question in completely different way but still i ll upvote your answer for your effort and time. Thank you all

Comment: Don’t accept it if it wasn’t the solution. Don’t upvote if it wasn’t helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$unity=[Regex]::Matches($filesys, "\(([^)]*)\)") -replace '[(\)]',''  -replace "T",""

$UnityCapacity = [pscustomobject][ordered] @{

Name = "$Display"

"Total" =$unity[0]

"Used" = $unity[1]

"Free" = $unity[2]

'Used %' = [math]::Round(($unity[1] / $unity[0])*100,2)
}``
```